# rsyslog capturing apacher logs in mongodb

Tags: apache-2.2, mongodb, rsyslog

I am trying to send my apache logs to mongodb via rsyslog

My rsyslog.conf looks like this:

```
module(load="imuxsock")
module(load="imklog")   
module(load="imfile")
module(load="ommongodb")


input(type="imfile"
    File="/var/log/apache2/access.log"
    Tag="Apache Access"
    mode="polling"
    PollingInterval=2
    Ruleset="mongo"
)

ruleset(name="mongo"){
    action(type="ommongodb" server="192.168.1.133" db="logs" collection="tester"  )
}


$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

At the moment a connection is being made to the mongodb database but nothing is being written to the collection.  Am I missing something obvious?